# Wordpress check user login info

Tags: wordpress

I using function wp_signon() for check user info, i only check user and password is true, that not login. When i call function and data is ok, so user will login.

So how can i fix problem. Because when call function, another user logout. and this user login.

this code:

```
 $creds = array(
        'user_login'    => 'mysuser',
        'user_password' => 'mypassword',
        'remember'      => false
    );

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

Comment: i user function wp_authenticate() so it's work.

Comment: Glad that you found a working function yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_signon()` is a function to sign in user with the provided credentials.

If you only want to check the password, using `wp_check_password()` is the way to go.

```
$creds = array(
    'user_login' => 'mysuser',
    'user_password' => 'mypassword'
);
$user = get_user_by('login', $creds['user_login']);
$isValidCreds = $user && wp_check_password($creds['user_password'], $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID));
```

[wp_check_password function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password)

Comment: @dungphanxuan Glad you were able to solve the problem! Please use the check mark to the top left of this answer to mark it as the solution :)